# Security measures with unsafe code on Docker

Tags: security, unix, docker

My intention is to make an LTI compliant web app where programming students can run Python code and the code can be graded. I will be using a Docker container to run the code a student has submitted, inspired by this project: https://github.com/hmarr/codecube On Codecube a user submits some code and the server runs the code in a docker container.

On the project above, the following safety measure is taken before running the unsafe user submitted code. Unfamiliar with user control side of Linux, the question is, does this make any sense? Is it worth doing this compared to the security benefits I might get out of this?

```
#server/entrypoint.sh
prog=$1
uid=$2
if [ -z $1 ]; then
echo "you must provide a file"
exit 1
fi
if [ -z $uid ]; then
uid=10000
fi
echo "127.0.0.1 $(hostname)" >> /etc/hosts

groupadd code
useradd -u "$uid" -G code -d "/home/codecube" -m codecube
#The next two lines should propably read /home/codecube because /code doesn't exist
chgrp code /code
chmod 0775 /code
cd /home/codecube
sudo -u codecube /bin/bash /run-code.sh $prog
```